# Cannot access NSDictionary key in FourSquare API venues

Tags: ios, json, dictionary, nsarray, foursquare

I'm trying to access the "prefix" and "suffix" strings in the following FourSquare NSDictionary. In my nsobject I've tried the following with no luck. Is there an easy way to access the strings? I've tried:

```
venue.photo = v[@"photo"];
venue.photo = v[@"photo"][@"prefix"];
```

and the NSDictionary prints:

```
{
    categories =     (
                {
            icon =             {
                prefix = "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/movietheater_";
                suffix = ".png";
            };
            id = 4bf58dd8d48988d17f941735;
            name = "Movie Theater";
            pluralName = "Movie Theaters";
            primary = 1;
            shortName = "Movie Theater";
        }
    );
    contact =     {
        formattedPhone = "(844) 462-7342";
        phone = 8444627342;
        twitter = regalmovies;
    };
    events =     {
        count = 9;
        summary = "9 movies";
    };
    hasMenu = 1;
    hereNow =     {
        count = 2;
        groups =         (
                        {
                count = 2;
                items =                 (
                );
                name = "Other people here";
                type = others;
            }
        );
        summary = "2 people are checked in here";
    };
    id = 4a2aac37f964a52034961fe3;
    location =     {
        address = "1471 W Webster Ave";
        cc = US;
        city = Chicago;
        country = "United States";
        formattedAddress =         (
            "1471 W Webster Ave",
            "Chicago, IL 60614",
            "United States"
        );
        lat = "41.92149057";
        lng = "-87.66487751";
        postalCode = 60614;
        state = IL;
    };
    menu =     {
        anchor = "View Menu";
        label = Menu;
        mobileUrl = "https://foursquare.com/v/4a2aac37f964a52034961fe3/device_menu";
        type = Menu;
        url = "https://foursquare.com/v/regal-webster-place-11/4a2aac37f964a52034961fe3/menu";
    };
    name = "Regal Webster Place 11";
    referralId = "v-1416373439";
    specials =     {
        count = 1;
        items =         (
                        {
                description = "";
                icon = default;
                id = 50355f96d86cbef3478adc65;
                interaction =                 {
                    entryUrl = "https://foursquare.com/device/specials/50355f96d86cbef3478adc65?venueId=4a2aac37f964a52034961fe3";
                };
                message = "Join us for Deal Days! ALL DAY Tuesday enjoy $6.50 tickets.";
                page =                 {
                    bio = "";
                    contact =                     {
                        twitter = regalmovies;
                    };
                    firstName = "Regal Cinemas";
                    followers =                     {
                        count = 12203;
                        groups =                         (
                        );
                    };
                    gender = none;
                    homeCity = "Knoxville, TN";
                    id = 12864010;
                    photo =                     {
                        prefix = "https://irs0.4sqi.net/img/user/";
                        suffix = "/DMGZGZVXT3NVLKNP.jpg";
                    };
                    tips =                     {
                        count = 347;
                    };
                    type = chain;
                };
                provider = foursquare;
                redemption = webview;
                state = unlocked;
                title = Special;
                type = frequency;
                unlocked = 1;
            }
        );
    };
    stats =     {
        checkinsCount = 23578;
        tipCount = 56;
        usersCount = 10220;
    };
    storeId = Chicago;
    verified = 1;
}
```

Comment: First, what you have printed is a dictionary, not an array. It seems that this dictionary has value for "items" which is an array of dictionaries (with one element in this case). The first dictionary in the items array has a dictionary for the key "page". The page dictionary contains a dictionary for the key "photo" which contains strings for the keys "prefix" and "suffix"

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out (im still learning). I've updated question and used: venue.photo = v[@"specials"][@"items"][@"page"][@"photo"][@"prefix"]; but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work -

```
NSArray *itemsArray=(NSArray *)venue[@"items"];
for (NSDictionary *specialDictionary in itemsArray) {
    NSDictionary *pageDictionary=(NSDictionary *)specialDictionary[@"page"];
    NSDictionary *photoDictionary=(NSDictionary *)pageDictionary[@"photo"];
    NSString *prefix=(NSString *)photoDictionary[@"prefix"];
    NSString *suffix=(NSString *)photoDictionary[@"suffix"];
    // Do something with prefix and suffix 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting error 'expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'FSVenue'. After researching do I add objectForKeyedSubscript: in my 'FSVenue' object to resolve?

Comment: Which object is FSVenue?  It seems that you don't have a plain NSDictionary, but you are using some library?  What is the URL for the library you are using.

Comment: It's the FourSquare venues/search API - https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search. Is this what you're referring to?

Comment: No, what type of object is `venue` from the error message it appears to be an `FSVenue` not a plain NSDictionary that you would get back from a JSONParser. Are you using some framework or library to interact with the API?

Comment: You're correct venue is FSVenue, apologies for confusion. I'm using Constantine's github https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/Foursquare-API-v2 The call uses NSURLRequest, if that answers your URL question.

Comment: Which line gives the error about FSVenue?  Looking at the GitHub repo, none of the data you have shown in your question is available from an FSVenue object

Comment: I've added the 'photo' code. The repo comes with 'name'. I'm using venue. and they use ann. The error occurs in the first line of code in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65233/discussion-between-paulw11-and-ryasoh).

Answer (score 0):

notice that there is a small bracket "(" in the key items, this line

```
items =         ( <----
                        {
                description = "";
                icon = default;
                id = 50355f96d86cbef3478adc65;
                interaction =                 {
```

pecials,items[0],page,photo,prefix
so the correct answer should be

```
 venue.photo = v[@"specials"][@"items"][0][@"page"][@"photo"][@"prefix"];
```

Comment: I gave it a shot but came with error: 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: you can check the size of items first

NSLog(@"size : %d",v[@"specials"][@"items"].size);

guessing that the items array sometimes may be empty??